# Boolean logic - How to determine if only one boolean is true in a list of boolean statements

Tags: java, boolean, computer-science, boolean-logic, boolean-operations

Essentially, is there a way to determine using boolean logic iff one boolean is true.

Comment: Yes. (Also this is absolutely not a programming question - so some other place would be more appropriate to ask one. And for similar question to be on topic on any SE sites you need to show effort to solve it along with exact problem you facing with your solution... and "yes/no" questions are really not useful )

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about theoretical part of boolean logic.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Boolean algebra is an underpinning of computer science. The science part of computer science. Not sure why you'd think this is off-topic.

Comment: Why not just loop through all your booleans and keep a counter of how many were true?  It might not be quite as fancy as using some complicated logical expression, but for the vast majority of people looking at it, it will be a lot more readable - it's probably less prone to a typing error as well.  It also would have the advantage of scaling relatively well for variable numbers of booleans - you could always break the loop when you hit the second true boolean.

Comment: @learner561 - are you working with a set of boolean values in a list, or an expression?